# Preventing "Force Close" and "Uninstall"

Tags: android, device-admin, device-policy-manager

How can I keep my company's app from being force closed and or uninstalled without authorization?

I know it can be done. I just done know the hows, because I have seen it in other apps.

Where I work, we own our devices and give them to our employees for use in their daily lives. We track our employees work day stops to verify address location. Lately we have had trouble with some employees removing our force closing or removing our app. We do not root our devices.

Comment: Use [Device administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: I did. I can uninstall and FC no problem. Unless there is something I'm missing. I am having trouble finding anything on Google. Either nobody knows how or they refuse answer based on ethics.

Comment: How can I require password to deactivate Device Admin?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably rather `device owner` (an not `device admin`) on Android. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices to start with.